# How do I convert a datetime in UTC to the server's local time using AT TIME ZONE in SQL Server 2016+

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone, utc, localtime

Using SQL Server 2016 or newer, I want to convert a datetime that represents a UTC value to local time on the server.

I would like to use AT TIME ZONE but it assumes you explicitly know what the server's time zone is. Our product may be installed anywhere around the world so I can't assume the time zone.

Is there a way (without using CLR or similar) to get the name of the server's time zone so I can use it in an AT TIME ZONE call?

Or is there another way in SQL 2016 to convert from UTC to server local?

```
-- how do set a value for @TZ that has the server's time zone name
DECLARE @TZ NVARCHAR(100) = 'Server Time Zone'
DECLARE @D DATETIMEOFFSET = '2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00' 
SELECT @D AT TIME ZONE @Tz
```

Comment: try this link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39421/how-to-handle-timezone-properly-in-sql-server

Comment: Thank you for the link to stackexchange, but that is pre-SQL 2016 and I think there are better options with the new "AT TIME ZONE" functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to do this in SQL 2016 without relying on a CLR or an xp_regread, neither of which I want to do due to the fact I want the SQL user to have minimal permissions.

In the end, decided to create a UDF that will return the server's time zone.

The creative part is that that the UDF is created dynamically, and the server's time zone is read using xp_regread at UDF **creation time**, and after that the time zone is essentially hard-coded in that UDF.

I am assuming that if a user has permissions to create a UDF, they likely also have permission to call xp_regread.  Once created, no special permissions are required.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the date difference in minutes between getdate() and getutcdate() to determine your difference from UTC and apply that to the new timestamp. [SQLAuthority](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/02/15/sql-server-get-current-timezone-name-in-sql-server/) also provides a great way to get the timezone for your server.

```
DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the getdate() and getutcdate() difference will give me the offset for the current time, but cannot be applied to historical or future dates due to DST issues and time zone changes. So that won't work for me.

I did see the SQLAuthority solution you mentioned, but my concern was around what privilege level the user must have to call xp_regread.  We are trying to address security concerns of our customers... and I don't think they will like us reading from the registry. I will look into this more though to see the permission/security implications. Thank you.

Comment: I've also seen getdate() and getutcdate() being off by 3 milliseconds when run in a query.  Maybe there is a way to get the server's UTC offset and add it to the getutcdate() return value????

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this in actual project application, but hope this helps.

```
DATENAME(TZOFFSET , SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
```

This should give you the server time offset, then try and query a matching timezone name to be used for AT TIME ZONE. it can probably return multiple matching timezone names, but we just need one as long as it had the same offset for accurate conversion.

Sample script below:

```
DECLARE @TimeZoneName NVARCHAR(100);
SELECT TOP 1 @TimeZoneName = name FROM sys.time_zone_info  WHERE current_utc_offset = DATENAME(TZOFFSET , SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
SELECT GETUTCDATE() AT TIME ZONE @TimeZoneName;
```

Comment: See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)